# Reassign non-variable tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a requirement, that I want to use the updated value of `x` as an input to RNN. The below code snippet might illustrate you in detail.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None,1])
RNNcell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(....)
outputs, _ = tf.dynamic_rnn(RNNCell, tf.reshape(x, [1,-1,1]))
x = outputs[-1] * (tf.Varaibles(...) * tf.Constants(...))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is more or less self-explanatory. We take the output of the model, multiply it by some tensor (could be scalar, or tensor with rank `> 0` that could be broadcasted), feed it again to the model and get the result:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((2, )))
output1 = tf.matmul(x, w) + bias

some_value = tf.constant([3, 3],      # <-- Some tensor the output will be multiplied by
                         dtype=tf.float32)
output1 *= some_value*x  # <-- The output had been multiplied by `some_value`
                         #     (in this case with broadcasting in case of
                         #     more than one input sample)

with tf.control_dependencies([output1]):   # <-- Not necessary, but explicit control
    output2 = tf.matmul(output1, w) + bias #     dependencies is always good practice.

data = np.ones((3, 2)) # 3 two-dimensional samples

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(output2, feed_dict={x:data}))
    # [[3.0432963 3.6584744]
    #  [3.0432963 3.6584744]
    #  [3.0432963 3.6584744]]
```

Comment: I guess, I am not clear about the question. Herein, I update `x` after RNNcell because the initial value I pass for `x` placeholder is user defined and I cannot skip that part.

Comment: First `x` is an input of `RNN`, then how do you want to use `x`?

Comment: Thats where my question comes in. 

`x` is input of RNN no change in it. After which I need to update the output of RNN with some multiplications and then I want to feed that value as input to RNN again.

Comment: output multiplied by the input? i.e. `RNN.output*x*c==input to RNN again`, where c is some constant OR `RNN.output*y==input to RNN again`, where `y!=x`. First or second ?

Comment: + what is the shape of the output of `RNN`? Same as `x`?

Comment: Second...I updated the code snippet in the question.

The input shape of RNN is (1, None, 1) and output shape is (None, 1). Here None depends on the batch size.

Comment: Updated, take a look

Comment: I tried to update my tf code with your logic but it throws error in ```output2 = model(output1, state)``` ...If you don't mind can you tell me where I am making mistake(updated the code in question)... Thanks

Comment: ```ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 1 for 'rnn/while/rnn/basic_rnn_cell/concat_1' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [3,2], [1,1], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.```

Comment: The dimension of ` tf.reshape(data, [1,-1,1])` must be the same as the dimension of `model` (i.e. of `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=1, activation=None)`)

Comment: sorry not clear...I know the dimension of ` tf.reshape(data, [1,-1,1])`  will be `(1,3,1)` i.e. timestep, batchsize, sequence ...But what about the model?

Comment: it would be helpful, if you could update your answer with tensorflow model.

Answer (score 1):

@Vlad answer is correct but since am new member cannot vote. The below code snippet is updated version of Vlads one with RNN cell.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None,1])
model = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=1, activation=None)

outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(model, tf.reshape(x, [-1,1, 1]), dtype=tf.float32)

# output1 = model.output 

# output1 = outputs[-1]
output1 = outputs[:,-1,:]
# output1 = outputs

some_value = tf.constant([9.0],     # <-- Some tensor the output will be multiplied by
                         dtype=tf.float32)
output1 *= some_value                # <-- The output had been multiplied by `some_value`
                                     #     (with broadcasting in case of
                                     #     more than one input samples)

with tf.control_dependencies([output1]): # <-- Not necessary, but explicit control
    output2, state2 = model(output1,state)
```

Comment: You cannot vote yet, but if you press on accept my answer button you will become 2 points closer to being able to vote ( especially if my answer is correct, as you say ;-) )